# How can I automagically make a checkout upon push?

Tags: git, githooks

Consider the following situation:

I have a git repository foo.git that contains code of a javascript project. In this repository there is a branch *production* that contains the state of the code as served by a web-server which fetches the code from `/var/www/foo`. This repository is the master repository for the project. Everybody pushes and pulls from/to it.

Is it possible to have `/var/www/foo` updated to a checkout of *production* whenever someobody pushes to that particular branch? You may assume that the git daemon (or the user git which is the user all people log in to to connect via SSH) is entitled to write to said directory.

Comment: So you have a git repository somewhere like /git/foo.git and when you push to the *production* branch there you want your webserver's git repository at /var/www/foo to pull your new commit?

Comment: @tewe Yeah. But there does not have to be a git repository at /var/www/foo. It's okay if /var/www/foo just contains a checkout.

Comment: Then you have to have an intermediate repository somewhere, I don't think you can checkout without a git repository, and you can't make the other one non-bare because then you can't push to the *production* branch if it's checked out there.

Comment: @tewe I recall it being possible to check out a specific revision of a (bare) repository into an arbitrary directory.

Comment: BTW if you combine my answer and @Jacob's then you get what you want.

Comment: I'm not aware of that but there may be a plumbing command for it. If you know it please share :)

Comment: @tewe See my answer below.

Comment: @tewe People suggested git archive in the IRC. Apparently there is no nice way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a bare repository on the server with `git init --bare`.
Then use a `post-receive` hook to trigger your deploy.
How you deploy is up to you.

### My Deployment Strategy

I usually place a `deploy` director, somewhere logical.
Then each checkout, I unpack the latest branch to `deploy/COMMIT_ID` where `COMMIT_ID` is the hash of the latest push. Once the checkout is complete, you can re-point a symlink to the latest deployment directory.

My usual directory structure:

```
deploy.git/
deploy/
    a7922231/
    b2f0a2af/
    latest -> b2f0a2af
```

#### Unpacking the Update

Rather than use a `git-checkout`, I usually use `git-archive` to unpack a branch into a directory.

```
# Assuming current directory is deploy.git
HEAD=`cat refs/heads/master`
mkdir -p ../deploy/${HEAD}
git archive master | tar -x -C ../deploy/${HEAD}
```

Your web-server can point to `deploy/latest`, updates will be more-or-less atomic.

I use this often in production, and has a few benefits over unpacking over the same directory.

1. rollbacks are easy
2. you can do post-unpack procedures, like compile or install dependencies without interrupting the current deployment

#### Tips

1. each update, append to a **deploy log** that says when updates occurred, and what their hash ids are. This makes rollbacks *much* easier.

Comment: How do you checkout into an arbitrary directory? What is the option I need to pass to git checkout?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a file called `post-receive` in your `/git/foo.git/hooks directory` (based on my comment above). Something like this (with some debug log):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Hook called'
pullneeded=false

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    echo "OLDREV $oldrev NEWREV $newrev REFNAME $refname"
    if [ "$refname" == "refs/heads/production" ]; then
        echo 'Pull needed'
        pullneeded=true
    fi
done

if [ $pullneeded ]; then
    echo 'Pull'
    cd /var/www/foo
    git --git-dir=/var/www/foo/.git pull
fi

echo 'Hook done'
```

You have to set up your git repository at `/var/www/foo` to track the *production* branch of your other repository. If it's called *origin* there then it is:

```
git branch --set-upstream production origin/production
```

And of course the *production* branch has to be checked out in your `/var/www/foo` repository.

**UPDATED**

Maybe a `post-update` hook is more appropriate (sample is from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6597728/299788):

```
#!/bin/bash    

case " $* " in
*' refs/heads/production '*)
    cd /var/www/foo
    git --git-dir=/var/www/foo/.git pull
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Instead of `cd /var/www/foo` you can add the parameter `--work-tree=/var/www/foo` to the git pull command next to the `--git-dir`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out a git repository `foo.git` into a directory `dir` with the following commands:

```
git archive | tar x dir
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course, I even wrote this in my comment to my answer :) Didn't think of it this way.