# Git Deployment Workflow that Takes Live Updates Into Consideration

Tags: git, deployment, hosting

### What I'm Looking for

We're looking for a Git host that has web-manageable deployments **via Git**. Most deployment software I've found uses FTP, and if there is an update made on the live server (some of our scripts generate occasional code changes) the FTP seems to blow away the live changes if the Repository has the same modified file (what would otherwise be a merge conflict). We've tried beanstalk, springloops and deployhq.

### Current Workflow

We currently have a cumbersome deployment process which involves committing the live code and pushing it to the Git server, then pulling to a developer machine, resolving any merge conflicts, then pushing back to the Git Server, then pull to the Live server.

---

Does anyone know of a service that can do differential deployments via Git, that may not deploy if there is a merge conflict, and just warn about the difference? This may be a Git Hosting service itself as well.

### Update

I made this infographic to help display our current workflow, and how we'd like to have our workflow:

[image: workflow infographic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer below for a git-based deployment strategy that we use daily.
It deploys to a fresh directory each update, so it will never have merge conflicts on the server. I *strongly* recommend against editing deployed code, but to each his own.

- [How can I automagically make a checkout upon push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667128/how-can-i-automagically-make-a-checkout-upon-push/14670278#14670278)

This isn't a hosting service however, it's do it yourself. Thus it doesn't quite answer your question, but it's worth noting.

Comment: Ah yes, We wouldn't have live code changes if we could avoid it. Unfortunately, we're dealing with legacy code that generates and modifies files based off certain Administrative events. Your link strongly reminds me of a Capistrano deployment method. However, I still don't see a smooth way of taking live changes into account. This might have to be a 'someday' luxury, once the legacy code is replaced.

Comment: What about just not tracking those files in Git? Leave them to persist on the server between updates.

Comment: Because it may modify files that we also modify for codebase changes. It's really, really annoying

Comment: I feel sorry for you. I would try to isolate the files that are changing. Other than that, you may consider adding the production server as a remote from your dev machine, that way you can skip push/pulling to Github (Git Host) etc.